# How is video playing on Chrome different from the Android WebView on Android 7+?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, chromium

Android 7+ uses Chrome for the `WebView` but yet there are some differences because some videos work on Chrome for Android but they don't work on the `WebView`.

Here are two examples:

http://www.americatv.com.ar/vivo

http://www.tvpublica.com.ar/vivo/

I have seen this also with globosat from Brazil, and a few other sites. Seems to be happening more and more. Usually changing the user agent doesn't help.

So what are these pages checking for or what is missing from the WebView that allows these videos to play on Chrome but not the `WebView`?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a user-agent that sometimes allows these to work? Do they ever work?  Are you setting a WebChromeClient? Does it work with 6.x?  Does it do audio only, no video?

Comment: Usually using a Chrome for Android user agent will allow some sites to work, but not these two sites or Globo from Brazil. I'm setting a WebChromeClient. I've tried this on several Android System WebView browsers and none of them work, so it isn't just about my browser. Doesn't work on Android 4.4 either. It actually used to work, this is a recent change and more sites seem to be changing to be this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach chrome to a [remote instance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) of your android WebView (in an emulator in my case), you see a few javascript failures (they also show up in the Android Monitor but they're harder to see there).

[image]

Particularly poignant is

```
  ... I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: chrome is not defined", source: http://iframe.statics.space/magma/main/js/cast.js (7)
```

So apparently in a WebView "chrome.X" are not defined (unclear if that's expected or not) but the website is expecting them.  So you could try and implement a "fake" chrome object and inject it (maybe), or perhaps try a Firefox useragent instead so it doesn't try chrome-y stuff:

`myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1");`

Comment: You seem to be right, and that Firefox user agent actually helped as well. I've reported all the script errors to the script authors that I was able to find. Thank you.